# VBA - Refresh Pivot Chart is shutting down Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am successfully creating a Pivot table using VBA and then I am trying to update a Chart using the data of the Pivot table I created (still in VBA).

The problem is, when I call the Chart update function Excel crashes and shuts down randomly (sometimes the chart is refreshing correctly, and somtimes it's not working).

Please find below the function I'm using to update the chart, I am only using the SetDataSource property:

```
Function GeneratePivotChart(wbSource As String, wbDestination As String, chartName As String, pivotName As String)
    With Sheets(wbDestination).ChartObjects(chartName).Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(wbSource).PivotTables(pivotName).TableRange1
    End With
End Function
```

To trigger the update I'm using the PivotTableUpdate event in the worksheet containing the pivot table.

Any idea why Excel would shut down while updating the data of the charts? Should I instead delete the chart and create a new one?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Are both the sheets (`wbSource` and `wbDestination`) in the same workbook? Also change `Function` to `Sub` as you are not returning anything...

Comment: Yes the sheets are in the same workbook. Thanks I changed it to a sub as well.

Comment: Ok I just tested it and the code didn't crash. May I see your workbook?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share this workbook. /

Comment: Do you know how to do error handling? You might try and see what happens when you trap the error?

Comment: I did put instructions to catch errors but I can't get anything. Excel is always poping up the window saying it stopped working normally and I have to restart it. The shut down happens sometimes when I try to save the document after I ran the procedure to refresh the pivot chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try **ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll** instead of PivotTableUpdate event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's still shuting down randomly though.